# Module parse failed: Unexpected token (110:28)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this error when I write a block scope function.

> Failed to compile
>
> > ./src/components/PlaceDetails/PlaceDetails.jsx 110:28
> > Module parse failed: Unexpected token (110:28)
> > You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> > |       columnNumber: 21
> > |     }
> > }, place.ranking)), place?.cuisine?.map(function (_ref2) {
> > |     var name = _ref2.name;
> > |     return /*#**PURE***/React.createElement(Chip, {

this is my function:
I use Travel Advisor api, 'place' is data from this api. cuisine its array.

```
                {place?.cuisine?.map(({name})=> (
                <Chip key ={name} size='small' label={name} className='chip' />
            ))}
```

Comment: The extra space between `key` and `={name}` ?

Comment: No, this error appears when I using ? (question mark) in the function

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using the babel/react scripts versions that are not supporting Optional chaining (?). Make sure that you have the following versions installed.

1. Create React App ≥ 3.3.0
2. Babel ≥ 7.8.0
3. TypeScript ≥ 3.7